# App crash on iPhone 7 but not on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone7plus

My Objective-c app is working well so far from iPhone 5 to iPhone 6s plus. But 2 days before I got some complaints from some iPhone 7 users, the app is crashing on their phone as soon as they installed the app. And when they tap the app icon also the app is crashing. But when I run it on iPhone 7 simulator I don't get any issue. I don't even have an iPhone 7 device to check this issue. Is there any way that I can catch this issue even using an online tool? Please suggest me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: You need more information, crashlogs for instance.

Comment: I cant get a crash log since I don't have any iPhone 7 device. I got this complaits from my clients

Comment: Try to add to your application some framework like crashlytics. Maybe you can handle crashlog with this framework.

Comment: Do you have crashlytics setup?

Comment: How can I add that? Can you provide more details about that tool?

Comment: No I havent setup that

Comment: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

Comment: Other way is to get crash log from device. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1747/_index.html

Comment: After add this framework do I need to run this on a device or is it enough to tun on semulator? But my semulator doesn't give any crash

Comment: To solve problem you need to have a crash report. You can add framework and send this build to the user which has iphone7, or you can try to tell this user to provide crash report for you.

Comment: @Sergey Thanks now I got the point

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what you’ll need to do to stop the apps from crashing or hanging immediately on open: Install any waiting software update, found in Settings > General > Software Update (it is likely versioned as 10.0.1 and the iPhone 7 may ship with iOS 10.0)

1. Install and let the iPhone reboot as usual
2. Open the App Store
3. Download any new app at all, literally any app, whether it is free or paid does not matter
4. You’ll see a pop-up message saying Terms and Conditions have changed, accept the new terms by tapping on the numerous “Agree” screens
5. Exit the App Store
6. Return to the Home Screen and launch the app(s) that were crashing initially

Source : http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/16/fix-apps-crashing-immediately-new-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my old app, then added the permission in Info.plist. like

**For Camera:**

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>You can take photos to document your job.</string>
```

**Photo Library**

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>You can select photos to attach to reports.</string>
```

Please check you app for other permission like microphone or other. I hope this will fix your problem.

If you are not satisfied from above answer then try **Instuments** to check any memory issue or other issue with iPhone 7

Comment: It crashes in the launch. As soon as user tap on the app icon.

Comment: If these permissions were missing, Apple would reject their app from approval (I know, because it happened to me) and it likely would not be model-specific.

Comment: Yeah my app is already approved by the appstore many versions